# Форма множественного числа

Tags: грамматика, множественное-число

В олимпиаде встретилось такое задание:

> Форма множественного числа существительного чаще всего указывает на
>   то, что предметов, названных этим существительным, больше одного,
>   именно на это и больше ни на что. Какое (какие) из выделенных слов в
>   приведенных предложениях может (могут) служить иллюстрацией этого
>   утверждения?
>
> 1. В горах выпал снег.
> 2. Он тщательно почистил зубы и умылся.
> 3. Бабушка испекла пирожки с капустой.
> 4. Скачки на приз мэра состоятся в начале августа.
> 5. Ни одно из выделенных слов не может служить иллюстрацией данного утверждения.

Не могли бы вы подробно объяснить, о чем идет речь в тексте задания? Какой ответ, по-вашему, правильный?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробую "перевести на русский" и тут, коли в прошлый раз у меня это получилось.

Это очередное задание из серии "угадай, в каком ухе у меня звенит".
Вернее о форме и содержании.
Угадать, видимо, надо, что автор имел в виду следующее.

Формы множественного числа (и тут не надо быть академиком) используются 
а) для образования собственно множественного числа, т. е. выражения семантики "два и более объектов" данного типа
б) выражения частично или полностью нового понятия (признаков, свойств, семантической собирательности).
Примеры опускаю, думаю, что понятно.

Иногда оба этих предназначения множественного числа переплетаются и сочетаются, в этом случае конкретное использование понятно только из контекста.

Так вот, автор, видимо, просит указать тот случай, когда значение типа б) по контексту отсутствует.

Да, его мысль понятна. **Горы** - географическое понятие, не просто две или несколько гор. **Скачки** - это вообще самостоятельное понятие, pluralia tantum, со "скачком" имеющее весьма отдаленную связь. С **зубами** несколько сложнее, но всё-таки можно договориться, что имеются в виду не просто несколько зубов, а совокупность зубов как орган (хотя именно в отношении чистки зубов такое понимание не очевидно).

В остатке вроде бы только бабушка с ***пирожками***. Всё бы ничего, но ведь "пирожки" - это кушанье. И в процессе выпекания, приготовления пищи, именно это понимание становится немаловажным.

Сравните: ***пельмень*** - это один маленький пирожок. А ***пельмени*** - в подавляющем большинстве случаев - еда, не просто несколько особей пельменя.

Остаётся предположить, что автор ориентировался на какой-то толковый(?) словарь, где зубы и горы (скачки - по умолчанию) приведены во множественном числе как исходной форме для понятия, а "пирожки" только как множественное.
Среди собственно филологических словарей такого не наблюдается (либо "зубы" - производное от "зуб", либо и "пирожки" тоже есть). Но вот в Википедии зубы во множественном присутствуют самостоятельно, а пирожки - только в статье "пирожок".

Короче, и формулировка, и ответ опять "оставляют желать".

Answer (score 1):

Выберем "бабушку": 3. Бабушка испекла пирожки с капустой.  Сравнить: Бабушка испекла пирог с капустой.

В горах ― это область, зубы ― не важно сколько, часть тела; скачки ― мероприятие.

Comment: Спасибо. А почему с зубами не важно? В ответах также 3. Только вот почему вы предлагаете к сравнению пироги, тогда как речь идет о пирожках?

Comment: Чистить зубы - это название гигиенической процедуры, о количестве зубов нет речи.  А с пирогами так: или вы печете определенное количество маленьких пирожков (уж точно больше одного),  или  всю капусту тратите на один большой пирог.

Answer (score 0):

Только 4-е предложение со словом "скачки" не соответствует поставленному вопросу.

Comment: А, если не секрет, почему?

Comment: потому что там одни скачки, а не много, как горы, пирожки...

Comment: Так в задании говорится: *предметов, названных этим существительным, **больше одного***.